# What's the meaning of "ol"?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

I seem to get *ol* mixed up with *al* a lot. There's probably an awesome explanation out there. I think I try to think of it as *than*, but it doesn't work exactly right in contexts like *antaux ol*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Ol* does translate to "than", but you can also think of it as more generally just indicating a comparison or difference. PIV lists these uses for it:

1. *por enkonduki la duan parton de neegaleca komparo* -> to introduce the second part of an unequal comparison (e.g. *Ŝi estas pli bela ol li*)
2. *por enkonduki diferencon inter du ebloj, ecoj ks* -> to introduce difference between two possibilities, qualities, etc. (e.g. *Ŝi havas malsaman ĉapon ol li*)
3. *por signi diferencon de tempo* -> to signify difference in time (e.g. *Ŝi foriris antaŭ ol li alvenis*

If #3 gives you trouble, it might help to think of it as a comparison between the two times (when she left vs. when he arrived), one comes earlier *than* the other.